# Supabase JS reponse no data property

Tags: next.js, supabase

I tried to configure a next js project with supabase

But the data I receive is not consistent

To do this I have configured the following 3 files :

.env.local

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL= ********
NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY= ********
```

supabase.js

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabase = createClient(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
)

export default supabase;
```

pages/api/posts.js

```
import supabase from '../../utils/supabase';

export default function handler(req, res) {
  const posts = supabase.from("posts").select("*");
  res.status(200).json(posts);
}
```

When I console log my posts variable, I have no data property.

It returned this,

```
PostgrestFilterBuilder {
  fetch: [Function (anonymous)],
  shouldThrowOnError: false,
  allowEmpty: false,
  url: URL {
    href: '********/rest/v1/posts?select=*',
    origin: '********',
    protocol: 'https:',
    username: '',
    password: '',
    host: '********',
    hostname: '********',
    port: '',
    pathname: '/rest/v1/posts',
    search: '?select=*',
    searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'select' => '*' },
    hash: ''
  },
  headers: {
    'X-Client-Info': 'supabase-js/1.35.4',
    apikey: '********',
    Authorization: 'Bearer ********'
  },
  schema: 'public',
  _subscription: null,
  _realtime: RealtimeClient {
    accessToken: null,
    channels: [],
    endPoint: 'wss://********/realtime/v1/websocket',
    headers: { 'X-Client-Info': 'supabase-js/1.35.4' },
    params: {
      apikey: '********'
    },
    timeout: 10000,
    transport: [Function: W3CWebSocket],
    heartbeatIntervalMs: 30000,
    longpollerTimeout: 20000,
    heartbeatTimer: undefined,
    pendingHeartbeatRef: null,
    ref: 0,
    logger: [Function: noop],
    conn: null,
    sendBuffer: [],
    serializer: Serializer { HEADER_LENGTH: 1 },
    stateChangeCallbacks: { open: [], close: [], error: [], message: [] },
    reconnectAfterMs: [Function (anonymous)],
    encode: [Function (anonymous)],
    decode: [Function: bound decode],
    reconnectTimer: Timer {
      callback: [Function (anonymous)],
      timerCalc: [Function (anonymous)],
      timer: undefined,
      tries: 0
    }
  },
  _headers: {
    'X-Client-Info': 'supabase-js/1.35.4',
    apikey: '********',
    Authorization: 'Bearer ********'
  },
  _schema: 'public',
  _table: 'posts',
  method: 'GET',
  cs: [Function: contains],
  cd: [Function: containedBy],
  sl: [Function: rangeLt],
  sr: [Function: rangeGt],
  nxl: [Function: rangeGte],
  nxr: [Function: rangeLte],
  adj: [Function: rangeAdjacent],
  ov: [Function: overlaps]
}
```

Also when I look at the dashboard of my supabase database I see that no query is receive

It seems that this query is not sent to the supabase API but I have no idea why ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to await the Promise: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select

```js
import supabase from '../../utils/supabase';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const posts = await supabase.from("posts").select("*");
  res.status(200).json(posts);
}
```